# Need help building a tree using jstree plugin and json in MVC?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, jstree

I am trying to build a tree using jstree plugin and Json in my MVC 4 project.
But i am doing something wrong and i can't figure it out.

This is my Json

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetTree(int idApp)
    {
        List<TreeNode> list = new List<TreeNode>();
        list = ClassData.GetAllClasses(idApp);
        var TopHierarchy = list.Where(x => x.ParentId == -1).FirstOrDefault();
        SetChildren(TopHierarchy, list);
        return Json(TopHierarchy, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Im my View (Index.cshtml) i have placed the div where tree is going to be displayed

```
<div id="treeView"> </div>
```

I have a dropdown menu and when i select a value in it, following script is triggered and it calls Json

```
function ApplicationChange() {
$('#loading').show();
var applicationId = null;
$("#Application option:selected").each(function (i, selected) {
    applicationId = $(selected).val();
});

$.ajax({
    url: pathTreeView,
    type: 'GET',
    data: { idApp: applicationId },
    success: function (json) {
        createJSTrees(json);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    },
    traditional: true


});

}

function createJSTrees(jsonData) {
$("#treeView").jstree({
    "json_data": {

        "data": jsonData
    },
    "types": {
        "types": {
            "default": {
                "select_node": function (e) {
                    this.toggle_node(e);
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "types", "ui"]
})
};
```

When i use Firebug and catch my Json response and use that string in jsfiddle the Tree is generated and everything is ok. But it won't generate im my application.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was wrong version of jsTree plugin.
I downloaded the latest version and everything is ok now.